# Malfuncion de los operadores con random en while en c#

Tags: c#, while, random

tardes o noches compañeros de programación, estoy haciendo un simple programa de girar un dado hasta que saques un 6, pero cuando pongo que repita mientras que la variable de Random no sea igual que 6, me saca "El operador "!=" no puede ser aplicado a variables de los tipos "Random" e "int"[CS0019]",ya intente convertir a float, a int y nada. Aqui va el codigo para ver si encuentran el error porfavor gracias

```
var dado = new Random();
int contador = 0;
while (dado != 6) {
  dado.Next(1,6);
  Console.WriteLine("Giraste un "+dado);
  contador++;
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee la documentacion de [Random](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0). Le tenes que pedir a la clase random, que genere el valor usando alguno de sus metodos (por ejemplo Next).

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te recomendaría hacer es asignarle a una variable lo que se genere con el metodo .Next() de tu objeto random previo a tu ciclo While.

```
var dado = new Random();
int valor=dado.Next(1,7);
int contador = 0;
while (valor != 6) {
  Console.WriteLine("Giraste un "+valor);
  contador++;
  valor=dado.Next(1,7);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

El problema en tu pregunta es que en primera, estabas utilizando el objeto "dado" para tu evaluación en el ciclo While, lo cual es incorrecto ya que lo estás comparando con un valor entero (6), por eso, previo al ciclo, propuse generar un valor con el metodo .Next().
También un problema que había es que debías aumentar el valor maximo de tu .Next a 7, ya que, como lo tenías en 6, nunca iba a generar ese valor. Para mayor comprensión del metodo, adjunto una referencia de su uso.
[Utilización del metodo .Next()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Gracias, de verdad me ayudaste.

Comment: @CatMatheus ¡No hay de que! gbianchi me ayudó en darte una mejor respuesta.
Si resolvió tu problema, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada:)